# Typescript error Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

I'm using typescript react.
xs,sm,md,lg are passed in props.
The px for each size (14px, 16px, 18px, 24px) is passed to Icon.
The error shown in (1) is displayed at the place where fontSize={FONTSIZE[size]}.
The error (2) is displayed at <AtomLinkProps['size'], string>.

error

```
①Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)  
②Type '(string & {} & ("xs" | "sm" | "md" | "lg")) | undefined' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.ts(2344)
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link as ChakraLink, LinkProps } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import { OpenExternalIcon } from './Icon/OpenExternalIcon';

export type AtomLinkProps = LinkProps & {
  iconType?: 'openExternal';
  size?: 'xs' | 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg';
};

const FONTSIZE: Record<AtomLinkProps['size'], string> = {
  xs: '14px',
  sm: '16px',
  md: '18px',
  lg: '24px',
};
export const Link: FunctionComponent<AtomLinkProps> = ({
  size,
  iconType,
  children,
  ...props
}) => {
  const Icon: Record<'openExternal', JSX.Element> = {
    openExternal: <OpenExternalIcon fontSize={FONTSIZE[size]} />,
  };
  return (
    <ChakraLink size={size} {...props}>
      {children}
      {Icon[iconType!]}
    </ChakraLink>
  );
};
```

[image]

image③
[image]

image④
erormessage

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"lg" | ({} & "xs") | ({} & "sm") | ({} & "md")' can't be used to index type 'Record<FontSizeType, string>'.
```

[image]

Comment: the cause could be that size is optional and can be undefined. Try to remove the "?" after size in type definition.

Comment: Well, as the error suggest, undefined cannot be used as an index type. Size is an optional property so it can be undefined.

Comment: Do not post images or your code or error-messages. Include them in text form

Comment: I'm sorry.
Where should I put the code for comments?

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, FONTSIZE doesn't take undefined to be an index which could happen if size is undefined. Either you can solve it by making `size` mandatory for your component or provide a default value as key to FONTSIZE

SOLUTION1:

```
export type AtomLinkProps = LinkProps & {
  color?: ColorType;
  iconType?: 'openExternal'; 
  // make size aa compulsory attribute rather than optional
  size: 'xs' | 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg';
};
```

SOLUTION2:

Instead of using AtomLinkProps to define `FONTSIZE` record key, you can use another type for `FONTSIZE` and then you can use default value while passing `size` as key to `FONTSIZE`

```
type FontSizeType = 'xs' | 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg';
export type AtomLinkProps = LinkProps & {
  iconType?: 'openExternal';
  size?: FontSizeType;
};
const FONTSIZE: Record<FontSizeType, string> = {
  xs: '14px',
  sm: '16px',
  md: '18px',
  lg: '24px',
};

<OpenExternalIcon fontSize={FONTSIZE[size || 'lg']} />,
```

Comment: <OpenExternalIcon fontSize={FONTSIZE[size || 'lg']} />, but I got the error shown in image 3).

Comment: Since you define `const FONTSIZE: Record<AtomLinkProps['size'], string>`, your AtomLinkProps has size as optional which is not excepted by the object FONTSIZE. You should make size mandatory or provide a type to FONTSIZE index which is not optional

Comment: I don't want to make fontSize mandatory.
How can I provide a non-optional type for the FONTSIZE index?

Comment: @aahhuhuhu I have updated my answer with SOLUTION2 which doesn't require you to make size mandatory

Comment: Is is possible for you to create a demo sandbox?

Comment: How do I make it?

Comment: You can use https://codesandbox.io/s/  and create a React Typescript type of code sandbox

Comment: Is it possible to install chakra ui in codesandbox?

Comment: yes, you caan add any  library as dependenccy

Answer (score 0):

problem is here

```
export type AtomLinkProps = LinkProps & {
  color?: ColorType;
  iconType?: 'openExternal';
  // size is optional so you can not use this property as index 
  size?: 'xs' | 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg';
};
```

i think it will solve the problem

> size: 'xs' | 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg';